# What is the meaning of this signature for `String.sub`: `(string, string) Blit.sub`

Tags: ocaml

I am learning / playing with ocaml in utop. Following the [real world ocaml book](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/).

So naturally I started with:

```
open Base;;
```

Next I try:

```
utop # String.sub "Hello world!" 3 4;;
Line 1, characters 0-10:
Warning 6 [labels-omitted]: labels pos, len were omitted in the application of this function.
Line 1, characters 0-10:
Warning 6 [labels-omitted]: labels pos, len were omitted in the application of this function.
- : string = "lo w"
```

Okay, more or less as expected. `Base` replaces many standard functions like `String.sub` with versions that use labeled arguments for clarity (arguably a good thing, so I have no complaint about that really).

But here's what's confusing to me. When I try to check the signature / type of the improved `String.sub`, I expected to see an improved function signature similar to the 'standard' `String.sub` signature (`string -> int -> int -> string`) but with labeled arguments. What I see instead is this:

```
utop # String.sub;;
- : (string, string) Blit.sub = <fun>
```

What is the meaning of that? And how can a (naive) user use this to determine the proper way to call the `String.sub` function?

I.e. how do I find out from a signature like `(string, string) Blit.sub`...

- that it is a function?
- what types of arguments it expects?
- what labels it expects on the arguments?
- what type of value it returns?

Comment: Documentation link for [`Base.Blit.sub`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/v0.12/doc/base/Base/Blit/index.html#type-sub). This links [here](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/v0.12/doc/base/Base__/Blit_intf/index.html#type-sub).

Comment: surely... that looks like a parameterized  `alias` .

Comment: [Blit.sub](https://github.com/janestreet/base/blob/221b085f3fcd77597f8245b4d73de3970b238e71/src/blit_intf.ml#L116) ultimately coming from [here](https://github.com/janestreet/base/blob/221b085f3fcd77597f8245b4d73de3970b238e71/src/blit_intf.ml#L30).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Blit.sub](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/v0.12/doc/base/Base__/Blit_intf/index.html#type-sub) is a type alias for a function type. But let's discover it ourselves. We can use the `#show` directive on the output to inspect its type, up until we get a satisfactory result,

```
# #show String.sub;;
val sub : (Base.String.t, Base.String.t) Base__.Blit.sub
# #show Base__.Blit.sub;;
type ('src, 'dst) sub = ('src, 'dst) Base__.Blit_intf.sub
# #show Base__.Blit_intf.sub;;
type ('src, 'dst) sub = 'src -> pos:int -> len:int -> 'dst
```

Now let's substitute the `'src` and `'dst` parameters with `string`, since we have `(string, string) sub`, and we get, the type of the [String.sub](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/v0.12/doc/base/Base/String/index.html#val-sub)

```
String.sub : string -> pos:int -> len:int -> string
```

It is much easier if you're using merlin and a suitable code editor. You can just ask the editor to unfold the type, so it takes several milliseconds to get to the root, and Merlin will also perform the substitution for you. For example, in my Emacs, it is just several repetitions of `C-c C-t` on the type. The same is for documentation that could easily be brought in by a single keystroke (not in this case though, as this function lacks documentation in Base). You can also easily jump to the definition or declaration of the function. So, if you want to be effective in OCaml, consider setting up a good development environment, like Emacs, Vim, Visual Studio Code, or some other.

Comment: "We can use the #show directive on the output to inspect its type, up until we get a satisfactory result" I tried something like that but it didn't work for me. I did `#show String.sub;;` => `val sub : (string, string) Blit.sub` (note how that looks different from your answer). Then `#show Blit.sub;;` gives me `type ('src, 'dst) sub = ('src, 'dst) Blit.sub`. But is weirdly circular, telling me that `Blit.sub` is `Blit.sub`, which gives no extra information and doesn't make it obvious to me what I should ask to `#show` next to get to the bottom of it. Are we using different versions of utop?

Comment: FYI: my utop is telling me `Welcome to utop version 2.9.1 (using OCaml version 4.14.0)!`.

Comment: Installed and setup vscode, and running into similar 'confusion' it shows the type of `String.sub` as `(string,string) Blit.sub` but I haven't found a way yet to make it explain to me what that alias expands to. Anyway, I will accept the answer as it explains to me what this means (i.e. a type alias, something I gather I will encounter further down the book, but which seems somewhat intuitive given above explanation :-). Would still be nice if I could learn / figure out how to actually 'follow the breadcrumbs' myself, which I have not yet been able to do as explained.

Comment: I was able to 'follow the breadcrumb' with my vscode. Using 'Goto type definition' on the 'String.sub' which highlights a line of code `type nonrec ('src, 'dst) sub = ('src, 'dst) sub`. Then hovering the righmost `sub` it shows the expected function type alias `type ('src, 'dst) sub = 'src -> pos:int -> len:int -> 'dst`. So its like a 'double' alias, both of which are called `sub`?

Comment: Ah, IIRC vscode is  unable to refine/dealias a type definition as it is not supported by the language server protocol. They are working on it,  but I don't know the status. Concerning the differences, I think it's the Base version, I am on a slightly older 0.13 version. The OCaml version is the same as yours.